# How to use generics in c# where two unrelated classes have identical property?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to write a generic method

```
GenericMethod<T>(T item) where T : class
{
   (if item.value1 == "something")
       doSomething
}
```

But I get an error:

```
T does not contain the definition of value1.
```

I searched through other answers in StackOverflow and tried to implement an interface and then changed method definition to `where T: dummyInterface`.

While this removes the error from method, I get the error while calling the method:

I need to call the method from two different classes: `GenericMethod(customerRet)` and `GenericMethod(vendorRet)`.

`GenericMethod(customerRet)` throws a compilation error:

```
accountRet should be convertible to dummyInterface
```

I also receive same error for `GenericMethod(vendorRet)`.

`customerRet` and `vendorRet` are not related in any way - no common interface etc.

Comment: Do you have a lot of operations that you need to perform on different classes or is this just a one off?

Answer (score 0):

the constraint you applied is `class`. At runtime you can pass in any class, which may or may not contain a property called `value1`. Instead of this you can specify the exact class you intend to use OR an interface that has a property `value1` for the constraint.

Comment: I am passing two separate classes in two different calls. So passing exact class is not an option .  When I use interface I get the error while calling the methods as I mentioned

Comment: any type that you intend to use with this generic method must have `value1`. How are you going to ensure this? So the classes `customerRet` and `vendorRet`both should implement this interface that contains `value1`.

Answer (score 0):

Either make `AccountRet` and `VendorRet` implement the `IDummyInterface`, in which case you no longer need a generic method:

```
PerformOperation(IDummyInterface item)
{
    if (item.value1 == "something")
        DoSomething();
}
```

Or make two overloads of the method **if you can't change the two classes for some reason**:

```
PerformOperation(AccountRet item)
{
    if (item.value1 == "something")
        DoSomething();
}

PerformOperation(VendorRet item)
{
    if (item.value1 == "something")
        DoSomething();
}
```

Your original code fails to compile as the compiler can't prove at compile time there's a property `Value1` on the generic `T` class - and in fact, this is *not* the case for *any arbitrary* `T` when there are no constraints.